# DropDownExtender In Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

in my web page i want to place the ajax Dropdownexteder. but it is not working fine this is my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Label  ID="lbldrp" runat ="Server" Text ="MyDropDown"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Panel ID="Mypanel" runat ="Server" >
          <asp:LinkButton ID ="linkmsn" runat ="Server" Text ="www.stackoverflow.com"></asp:LinkButton><br />
          <asp:LinkButton ID ="linkgoogle" runat ="Server" Text ="www.google.com"></asp:LinkButton>
        </asp:Panel>

        <cc1:DropDownExtender ID="DropDownExtender1" TargetControlID ="lbldrp" DropDownControlID ="Mypanel"  runat="server" >                 

        </cc1:DropDownExtender>
        <cc1:AnimationExtender ID="AnimationExtender1"  TargetControlID ="Mypanel"    runat="server">
        <Animations>
          <OnShow>
            <HideAction Visible="true" />
          </OnShow>
          <OnHide>
            <HideAction Visible="false" />
          </OnHide>
        </Animations>          
        </cc1:AnimationExtender>            

    </form>
```

it is giving some error like

```
"Animation on TargetControlID="Mypanel" uses property AjaxControlToolkit.AnimationExtender.OnShow that does not exist or cannot be set"
```

help me thank you.

Comment: I think OnShow will not be suppoerted in animation extender

Comment: @sashidhar have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hai Sasidhar **OnShow** and **Onhide** are not valid properties of **ajaxcontroltoolkit:animationExtender**, instead u can use **OnMouseOver for OnShow** and **OnMouseOut for OnHide**

Look at this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/AnimationExtender01242008065540AM/AnimationExtender.aspx

or

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Animation/Animation.aspx and check its properties

Comment: Hi pandiya i will check this link ok then i will get back to you

Comment: @sashidhar are you using ajaxcontroltoolkit

Comment: ya i take a new project with and added dll in bin and add ajax tools in tool bow

Comment: Pandiya the link you send i referred it and i take a ajax enbled website and place that code it is working fine but it is not related to dropdownextender na! is there any link related dropdownextender give me i will check out thank you for response

Comment: @sashi just change OnMouseOver for OnShow and OnMouseOut for OnHide

Comment: Sorry i did a mistake. i didn't take ajax enabled websiste. when i take ajax enabled site and i try the dropdownextender it is working fine. i have a doubt if i not take the ajax enable website, ajax will work or not? thank you for response.

Comment: Pandiya drop down extender working fine but when i click on the lable it will show the dropdown list but it is not going back when i click on empty space in the page this is my code can you check out and  i place the link buttons in the dropdown list when i click on the links it is not redirecting can you check once this is my code check out in next message

Comment: <asp:Label  ID="lbldrp" runat ="Server" Text ="MyDropDown"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Panel ID="Mypanel" runat ="Server" >
          <asp:LinkButton ID ="linkmsn" runat ="Server" Text ="www.msn.com"></asp:LinkButton><br />
          <asp:LinkButton ID ="linkgoogle" runat ="Server" Text ="www.google.com"></asp:LinkButton>
        </asp:Panel>
        <cc1:DropDownExtender ID="DropDownExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID ="lbldrp" DropDownControlID ="Mypanel" >
             <Animations >
               <OnShow>
                see next mesage

Comment: <OnShow>
                 <HideAction Visible="true" /> 
               </OnShow>
               <OnHide>
                 <HideAction Visible="true" /> 
               </OnHide>                
             </Animations>
        </cc1:DropDownExtender>

Comment: i change my code just i place the animation tag out side of <cc1:DropDownExtender > it is working fine but links which i place in panel when i click on them they r not working

Comment: sorry once again i made a mistak in link button i did not write postbackurl property that is why it is not redirecting do you find it?

Comment: but the feel and look of my dropdownextender  is not matching with ajaxsamplewebsite like when i click on label the dropdown box coming like plain link button where as in ajaxsamplewebsite the dropdown list is coming in a style format did you find this in my code pandiya

Comment: i will check out that link ok